# php - Cpanel create new folder with php code in cpanel

Tags: php, cpanel

I have been trying to create a script to login to my clients cpanel and create files or folders this my code so far i would like to get some help please.
I am using xml api to access my clients accounts.

```
<?php 
  include("xmlapi/xmlapi.php"); 

  $ip = "127.0.0.1"; 
  $auth_user = $_POST['txtcpusername']; 
  $auth_pass = $_POST['txtcppassword']; 

 //this is the part I am not sure about 
 $xmlapi->api2_query($username, "Fileman", "addf", 
 array("op"=>"unlink", "sourcefiles"=>''/public_html/subdomain.domain')
 );
```

Comment: I'm confused. Can you give a clearer statement as to what you're trying to acheive?

Comment: why are you referencing an array instruction of `unlink`,that doesn't correlate with `create files or folders` .

Comment: And why are you using CPanel username and password POSTs?

Comment: @Martin i am not sure how to do it , those Posts are comming from an html form which when a user submits the form.

Comment: i want to create folders in cpanel for my clients , in other words i want to login to their cpanel and create folders for them ... i have done it with email creation . i am looking for help now on how to create folders in my clients cpanel account

Comment: the line with an array is the one i am not sure about

Comment: To be honest I think you need to go away and read up a lot more about CPanel and WHM and how that system actually works. The whole point of CPanel is that users can themselves carry out validated tasks, such that (if you allow it), a user can log in and add their own folders. I very much doubt CPanel would allow remote access (PHP script, etc) to edit folders.Instead perhaps you simply need to use [PHP make directory](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php).

Comment: Martin i am aware of that , but am designing a system which will allow customers to do both .... directly login to their cpanel and do it in my client area which will be very easy for my users .. i am very aware of how WH and Cpanel work , correction cpanel allows remote acces , for an example i have a php script to create emails and email forwarding, i also have a script that does domain forwarding so Martin anything is posible with code

Comment: once i get it right ill come back and share..

Comment: If you want to make folders then I would expect that the PHP `mkdir` I linked to you would do what you want, if it's running on the same System as Cpanel

Comment: ive tried that one its not working because my script is running on a different account

Comment: I didn't know that. You need to add all the information you've added in these comments into your original question, it will help a lot more people answer your query.

Comment: To be honest, if CPanel allows the user to login anyway (as you state), then by adding your own system for editing their CPanel account you're simply making their CPanel account significantly less secure, I really doubt your security skills are up to the same level as CPanel developers. (and I don't think they're *great*). Perhaps less trying to reinvent the wheel and more trying to build a better carriage?

Comment: can i get someone else suggestion :)

Comment: why don't you just login as root and create folders in their /home/username directory, then chown to username:username and done

Comment: @Howard i think that could work .. i am working on it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found a solution .. i create subdomain (e.g facebook/domain.com) and then i remove remove the subdomain . in publick html the folder facebook will be created even if i have deleted the sub domain all that i do it with a php script :).

```
'$xmlapi = new xmlapi('x.x.x.x');
 $xmlapi->password_auth('root', 'password');
 $xmlapi->set_debug(1);

 // create sub domain
 $xmlapi->api1_query($username, 'SubDomain', 'addsubdomain', array($subDomain, $domaindomain, 0, 0, '/public_html/subdomain.domain'));

 // delete sub domain
 $xmlapi->api1_query($username, 'SubDomain', 'delsubdomain', array($subDomain, $domain, 0, 0, ''/public_html/subdomain.domain''));
 '
```

its a very useful piece of code  :)